# Display nodes under Parent Taxonomy in Views

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, views

I am using Drupal 7, and I created a two-level vocabulary used it as a field for term reference. I created it using
[Simple hierarchical select](https://drupal.org/project/shs) module.

*edit* : I have my node tagged with both the parent(State field), and child (City field) term.

**Location**

```
 - State1 
   - City A
   - City B
 - State2
   - City C
   - City D
```

Then I have a page View, where I use the Location field as an exposed filter, so that visitors can sort the content.

I have no problem in getting the results when the user selects for example:

> - Illinois
>
>   - Chicago

Then all content that has the term `Illinois` **and** `Chicago` will be displayed.

The problem comes when I only want to sort using the parent term, so if you sort for example using only

> - Illinois

It should display every node that has the term `Illinois`.  But my Views returned nothing, when selecting only the parent term and applying that exposed filter.

I have checked that when you look view the taxonomy of `Illinois` everything displays properly, but not on the exposed filter in Views.

How will I proceed on displaying the nodes in my Views using exposed filters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to work this one out.

Apparently you can add a filter using two methods:

- "Simple hierarchical select"
- "Content: Has taxonomy terms (with depth; Simple hierarchical select)"

Select the second method `Content: Has taxonomy terms (with depth; Simple hierarchical select)` as the filter.

Then after selecting the filter, you then have the option to select which taxonomy term to use. After that just select `Simple hierarchical select`.

Next step was to just simply expose the filter to users, so they can manipulate it.